# Can I update a locked Record using Partner API?

Tags: api, approval-process

I have the following implementation:

1) Users create a process in SF, when the process is ready for the financial department they submit for approve. The record is locked.

2) When the approval is done, the record is kept locked.

3) Using a Partner API, a custom integration app pulls approved records, and starts the ERP processing, during this process i need to update some custom record fields e.g. (Status, Totals, etc).

This raises the question can i update the locked record ?

Do i need to ask specific permissions configured on the object ?

Is there other way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the API follows the same rules as the UI for business logic. System Administrators (those with Modify All Data) can update the record via any means available to them, as well as anyone else allowed by the approval process configuration.

Comment: When you said "anyone else allowed by the approval process", you can't update unless you unlock the record, and then to lock again you need to submit for approval. If this is correct the only option is to be an Admin. Can you suggest an alternative to the use of Approval/IsLocked ?

Comment: No, a normal user can edit the record if the approval process allows them to. They can't unlock the record without being a system administrator or someone approved for editing the record anyways. Review your approval process configuration and you'll see what I'm talking about.